# Using CustomTaskPane.Window to distinguish between panes

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

C# Add-In for Excel.

I want to use the **CustomTaskPane.Window** property in order to know if a pane belongs to the active Workbook.
This is my code:

```
var activeWnd = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow;
var pane = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(myUSerCtrl, "title", activeWnd);
IntPtr panePtr = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(pane.Window);
IntPtr activeWndPtr= Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(activeWnd);    
bool sameWindows = panePtr.Equals(activeWndPtr);
```

When I inspect **sameWindows** it is **false**. And the pointer values are different, too
Is there a problem with my code, or these properties are not reliable?
Shouldn't both pointers point to the same window?
How else can I compare them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
if((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Window)myPane.Window).Hwnd     
== 
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Hwnd)
```

Will it work OK? I tried and it works but I am wondering if it is the right thing to do?

Answer (score 0):

As a result, you get pointers to the `IUnknown` interface which doesn't make any sense there.

Instead, I'd recommend casting the window to the `IOLEWindow` interface and then call the `GetWindow` method. Both explorer and inspector windows implement the specified interface. Then you may compare window handles.

Comment: This method did not work. I get a run-time exception: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).' Not sure how to fix it.