# IOLEWindow Interface not (no longer?) working

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.5

We have had this piece of code in our application for a long time, and as far as we know it was working fine until now:

(Please note that I have removed any code that is irrelevant to the problem, e.g. in my actual code the interface also contains the definition for ContextSensitiveHelp and the methods are in the correct order)

```
<ComImport(), Guid("00000114-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)> _
Private Interface IOleWindow
    Sub GetWindow(<System.Runtime.InteropServices.Out()> ByRef phwnd As IntPtr)
End Interface

Public Sub New(ByVal oOriginal As Object)
    Dim oFoo As IOleWindow = Nothing

    Try
        oFoo = TryCast(oOriginal, IOleWindow)
    Catch

    End Try
    If Not (oFoo Is Nothing) Then
        Try
            oFoo.GetWindow(hWnd)
        Catch

        End Try
    End If
End Sub

Public Shared Function GetHwnd(ByVal oOriginal As Object) As IntPtr
    Dim hWnd As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
    Dim oFoo As OLEWindow = Nothing

    Try
        oFoo = New OLEWindow(oOriginal)
    Catch

    End Try
    If Not (oFoo Is Nothing) Then
        hWnd = oFoo.hWnd
    End If

    oFoo = Nothing

    Return hWnd
End Function
```

The problem occurs in the TryCast

```
oFoo = TryCast(oOriginal, IOleWindow)
```

This no longer appears to be working. The variable oFoo is still "Nothing" after this line is called, and as a result it is not able to establish the Window handle of the oOriginal object that is passed in.

In case it matters: The target framework for the project is .NET Framework 4.5.2 and the oOriginal object is a Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Window. The project has a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word 14.0.0.0. The application is compiled for x86

**Can anyone explain why this is no longer working?**

We were able to code around the issue by adding the following code to get the Window Handle when the above fails:

```
Try
    hWnd = New IntPtr(CLng(oOriginal.Hwnd))
Catch
    hWnd = IntPtr.Zero
End Try
If hWnd = IntPtr.Zero Then
    Try
        hWnd = oOriginal.Handle
    Catch

    End Try
End If
```

...but I consider that to be a bit of a "whack it and hope" approach, which doesn't sit right with me. So if anybody can tell me what is wrong with the original code and how to improve it without having to resort to that latter approach, that would be wonderful.

Comment: Meanwhile I have been searching around and I come across this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56877357/using-customtaskpane-window-to-distinguish-between-panes

Note the comment added by Eugene Astafiev and the reply. When I remove the TryCast from the offending statement it seems at first like it has worked. oFoo appears to be an IOleWindow rather than "Nothing" - BUT when I then try to invoke GetWindow I get the same 0x80004002 error that user1523271 mentions in his or her reply ... so any help would be greatly appreciated :(

Comment: Since this was _working fine until now_, I wonder if this is another byproduct of the [Windows August 2019 Update](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/aaa04817-b2f4-4a0c-8050-b896374188a4/latest-windows-10-update-breaks-vba).

Comment: [Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IOleWindow.GetWindow(IntPtr) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.ole.interop.iolewindow.getwindow).

Comment: TnTinMn I wouldn't be surprised.
Jimi - as far as I can tell that's exactly how I declared it, albeit in VB.NET syntax. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Hi Jimi - ok I found Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.dll in several places on my machine. Took one matching my current Visual Studio, added a reference to it to my project and tried:

oFoo = TryCast(oFoo, Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IOleWindow)

Doesn't work either. Just like my own code it leaves oFoo Is Nothing.